# How do I lock and unlock the OSD of a "AOC monitor 21'"?

Tags: display

My AOC monitor 21' has an on-screen display, but I'm wondering how its lock function works.

Can you help me figure out how to lock and unlock the OSD?

Comment: Can you clarify "AOC monitor" and what you mean by locking / unlocking it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

According to [aoc page](http://aoc-europe.com/manuals/TFT_203Swa/English/v-04.htm) you need to do the following for one of the displays:

> OSD Lock Function: To lock the OSD, press and hold the MENUbutton while the monitor is off and then press power button to turn the monitor on. To un-lock the OSD - press and hold the MENUbutton while the monitor is off and then press power button to turn the monitor on.

If it doesn't work try searching for your display on the page. Or check the manual you got with monitor.

Comment: hold MENU for 5 seconds before turning it back on!

Comment: Also try holding in the button (left or right, try both) **while** you push the power button (as mentioned in the other answer, which I only now saw) :)

Comment: Thank you @T.Kaltnekar ! May AOC take notice of you and award you like a million dollars! For anyone for whom it may help: My specific use case was that, while connecting to my MAC in full HD (1080p) it kept saying "Input Not support" (sic). Clicking "Reset" from the unlocked OSD resolved this issue!

Comment: YES! Finally!!! If you have the joystick-button, hold it down for 10 seconds and it unlocks... finally... my god...

Answer (score 16):

OSD Lock Function:

To lock the OSD-First make the Monitor off by pressing power button and then hold the Left button for 5 seconds and simultaneously hit the power button with the left button and the osd is Locked.

OSD UnLock Function:

To Un-lock the OSD - Repeat the above same Process and Then OSD is Unlocked

Answer (score 4):

My one is AOC. What I did is, First turn off the power button and then press the power and menu button together, if its shows on the display the OSD lock message then it means its hasn’t worked but if not then it means it worked... I tested this myself

Comment: It worked. I have e2043Fsk  model and it doesnt have buttons but touch panel. Amazing!

Comment: This worked for me on a U2868, turned off pressed on and menu together and then when it turned on the menu worked again

Answer (score 2):

If your AOC e2343F is locked then just power off your screen and hold power and menu buttons together. Then you'll get your screen unlocked.

Comment: Worked for my e2343f - note the menu button is on the right - a square with 3 lines in it

Answer (score 1):

I was also caught in same problem, I figured out that configuration is different for different model of AOC, better you see your manual carefully.

On my model, manual says, while monitor is off, press left key button and press monitor-on button together to lock/unlock the osd.
[I know the post is older, just writing the answer, perhaps it helps someone.]

Answer (score 1):

To unlock the OSD lock, Press and hold the menu button for 10 seconds then the menu will appear.To lock OSD press and hold the menu button for 10 seconds.