# Command to unlock monitor

Tags: display

My AOC monitor which is model e2043Fk is locked.  How do I unlock it ?? We have tried pressing the power and menu buttons together but that did not work.  It worked fine yesterday but after it was turned off last night, it is locked and we cannot unlock it.

Comment: Does this link tell you? https://www.fixya.com/support/t14613281-aoc_e2043fk_osd_locked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first turn off the monitor, then hold menu button and only then turn on the monitor and wait holding the menu button for a bit.

This is the same for turning the lock on or off.

Comment: Agree with LPChip   ........ https://superuser.com/questions/31973/how-do-i-lock-and-unlock-the-osd-of-a-aoc-monitor-21#:~:text=OSD%20Lock%20Function%3A%20To%20lock,to%20turn%20the%20monitor%20on.